# ImageX in Windows PE is complaining that the subsystem is not present

Tags: imagex, windows-pe

I'm trying to use ImageX from the [Windows PE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749311%28WS.10%29.aspx) command line. When I run a [capture command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749447%28WS.10%29.aspx) from the console

```
cmd> e:\imagex.exe /capture <whatever>
```

I get a nasty error like

> the subsystem needed to support the image type is not present

What does that mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: can someone add the `windows-pe` tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That often occurs when one of the tools you've included in your [Windows PE disk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749311%28WS.10%29.aspx) (step 2) is not the correct architecture. Make sure that you copy the right `imagex.exe`. Here's how they should have written that line in the instructions.

```
c:\program files\<version>\Tools\**<architecture>**\imagex.exe
```

I've taken the liberty of scripting the entire process (for ISOs on x86 and x64 architectures with imagex support). You can pick up the scripts on my [github repo](https://github.com/AnthonyMastrean/chocolateypackages/blob/master/packages/wim2vhd/) or as a [chocolatey package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/wim2vhd).

Comment: +1 - Incorrect CPU architecture is the likely culprit.

Comment: The link for "github repo" is the same link as for "Windows PE disk" and the link for "chocolatey package" does not exist in your post.

Comment: Sorry about that... not sure what happened. Links are corrected now.